# git sparse checkout not able to download the required subfolder

Tags: git, powershell

I am using PowerShell to do a sparse checkout from git. The commands do not download any of the subfolders which I want to download. The output folder is empty with only '.git' being available . The subfolder /extract is not downloaded.

```
  $file = '/extract'
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"git init"
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"git version"  
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"git config core.sparsecheckout true"
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"git remote add -f origin https://mydomain/Projectname/_git/reponame"
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"echo $file >> .git/info/sparse-checkout"
  Invoke-Expression -Command:"git pull origin main"
```

The output I get is

```
  Initialized empty Git repository in D:/application/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/job1/Release_Scripts_0/.git/
  git version 2.30.0.windows.1
  From https://mydomain/Projectname/_git/reponame
   * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
  From https://mydomain/Projectname/_git/reponame
   * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Any suggestion why I am unable to download the required folder ( /extract ) in this case.

Comment: Unrelated to the git problem: `Invoke-Expression` is entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sure